# bash - source builtin and $HISTCMD variable

Tags: bash

I encountered an unexpected behaviour from the bash 'source' builtin concerning the display of the `$HISTCMD` environment variable.

I have a `init_things` file containing:

```
echo $HISTCMD
```

I type the following in a bash shell:

```
$> echo $HISTCMD
100

$> cat init_things
echo $HISTCMD

$> source init_things
1
```

I expected the last command to display 102.
I tried it on a zsh shell; it displays 102 as expected.

Is there a way to make bash behave as I expect? (without resetting the HISTCMD value to 1 in 'init_things')?

Why is bash behaving in such a way? (I couldn't find the answer in bash man page)

Is it related to bash "interactivity"?

> bash version: 4.3
>
> zsh version 5.1

Comment: apparently setting the history option solves my problem; `set -o history` in my init_things file

Comment: scripts don't use history by default

Comment: OK. it seems natural for forked bash scripts, it is less than obvious for sourced ones as we stay in the same bash process. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What do we know about histcmd?

```
   HISTCMD
      The  history  number,  or  index in the history list, of the current
      command.  Assignments to HISTCMD are ignored.  If HISTCMD is  unset,
      it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.
```

What other secrets can we learn from the manual?

```
   HISTCONTROL
      A  colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved
      on the history list.  If the list of  values  includes  ignorespace,
      lines  which  begin with a space character are not saved in the his‐
      tory list.  A value of ignoredups causes lines matching the previous
      history  entry  to not be saved.  A value of ignoreboth is shorthand
      for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A value  of  erasedups  causes  all
      previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the his‐
      tory list before that line is saved.  Any value  not  in  the  above
      list  is  ignored.   If  HISTCONTROL is unset, or does not include a
      valid value, all lines read by the shell parser  are  saved  on  the
      history  list,  subject  to the value of HISTIGNORE.  The second and
      subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command  are  not  tested,
      and are added to the history regardless of the value of HISTCONTROL.
```

Specifically:

> A value of ignoredups causes lines matching the previous history  entry  to not be saved.

Is that the cause of the issue? maybe...

```
$ echo $HISTCONTROL 
ignoredups:
```

...but not likely.

Can we reproduce this in a recent bash?

```
$ source init_things 
7615
$ . init_things 
7616
```

No, not really. Can we reproduce this in bash 4.3?

```
$ . init_things 
1
```

Yes!

There are a couple of lines about HISTCMD in the [CHANGELOG](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bminor/bash/master/CHANGES), but neither describe this particular issue. I guess it's just a bug in the way HISTCMD was initialized when encountered via `source` before.

Comment: It's just one of those bugs, I guess. Track history if bash is not flawless in that regard.